# DFP expandable ads

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-dfp

i've supplied an adv creative to a publisher that use Doubleclick for publisher to distribuite the ad unit.
For standard masthead there is no problem, but for expandable masthead i cannot figure out how to do.
My adv creatives ad IAB compliant so for expanding creative i use safeframe standard, but on publisher rendered iframe there is no object $sf, so no safeframe.

What API can i use in DFP iframe for expanding creatives? It is safeframe compliant?

Also the expanding creative loaded have height=1px, i don't know why.

I've tested my safeframe implementation here: http://safeframes.net/examples/creative_test.html
and works like a sharm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the publisher actually using async serving or is the creative actually wrapped in a Safe Frame?

The reason I am asking is because if the publisher uses synchronous serving and haven't selected to wrap the creative in SafeFrame, there will be no such.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you don't display ad from SafeFrame, but from Friendly Iframe, or you call DFP synchronicaly. Try to debug your ad unit on page, if it came from SafeFrame https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/7449957?hl=en&ref_topic=7362877.